# Using "Or" opertor in EntityFieldQuery

Tags: database

could you help me to fix my problem?
note:
each user have two field (fields are taxonomy reference)

I want to get two fields with `OR` condition
the output of my code returns in the shape of `AND` result

here is my code :

```
 $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
        ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
        ->fieldCondition('field_software_abilities', 'tid', $abilities, 'IN')
    ->fieldCondition('field_other_abilities', 'tid', $abilities, 'IN');
    $result = $query->execute();
```

I read an article about using addtag and `hook_query_tag_alter()`
but I can't use it

Answer (score 0):

EntityFieldQuery does not support `'OR'` operators. There is a workaround presented here ['OR' Queries with EntityFieldQuery](http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/or-queries-with-entityfieldquery/)  where an `'OR'` operator is added.

Comment: thank you for your answer I read this article but I can't use it in my code   would you please tell me how I can use that?